# TI-BASIC: Why am I getting an undefined error when all of my variables are defined?

Tags: variables, math, undefined, formula, ti-basic

```
Disp "SURFACE AREA:","4πR^2"
Input "RADIUS:",R
4πR^2->A
Disp "SURFACE AREA:",A,"UNITS SQUARED"
Pause
```

I'm trying to use this TI-BASIC code on my ti-84 plus, but everytime I use this string of code, it gives me an undefined error, even though it seem that all of my variables are indeed defined. Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `A <- 4*π*R^2`?

Comment: Why is the **surface** expressed in "units **cubed**"?

Comment: I cannot go to the left when storing variables, only right. And yes, it should be squared, my bad. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot replicate this error. I've tried your exact code and it ran fine. Are you sure you are typing it here exactly as you ran it? What inputs are you using? At which point does the error happen? Do any of the variables have values before you run the program? Have you recently run any other programs on the calculator that might have corrupted the memory?

Answer (score 0):

This statement gives the error.

```
4πR^2->A
```

Let's walk through this statement together.
`4πR^2` is correct so far. Let's head on over to the next part.

```
->A
```

However, you wrote `->` instead of `→`. TI-OS expects there to be another number after the minus (`-`), yet it finds the greater than symbol (`>`). The correct version of this line is:

```
4πR^2→A
```